# Integrating AppRTC to Ionic - iOS linker error

Tags: ios, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, apprtc

I am integrating AppRTC to my hybrid app (ionic 3 and angular 4)...

iOS AppRTC Integration: https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios

I've successfully installed the pod and build the project without errors but when I add

```
 [RTCPeerConnectionFactory initializeSSL];
```

to my

```
  application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

When I build the project I get the following errors:

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCPeerConnectionFactory", referenced from:

  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o

  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
  invocation)
```

Already searched the net but couldn't find a solution...

Added " ${inherited} $(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -ObjC -all_load" to the linker library, restart and clean xcode, deleted the DerivedData file but the issue still persist.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help as you have installed from a pod but we got the same error when the framework search path was wrong. $(inherited) pathToWebrtcFramework. With this option we had built the webrtc framework ourselves using the instructions at https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/.

Also set build active architecture only to yes.